# Import/include external VirtualHost files from directory to be used inside Apache's httpd.conf

Tags: virtualhost, centos7, httpd.conf

Would there be a solution to import all files with virtual host records in to httpd.conf ?

For single file this solution works fine:

```
include domain1.conf
include domain2.conf
include domain3.conf
```

But can't find the solution to include all files from a particular directory,
I tried

```
include  /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/*
```

but dos not seems to be reading anything from /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/

Answer (score 0):

Add extension of configuration file names by example:

```
include  /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

And check files and directory permissions at  `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts`. Apache user must have permission to read all from this directory.